# Running an AJAX code on the submit of a form

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, email

Here's my form:

```
<form action="/scripts/addemail_fb.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" value="Enter your email here!" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

And my jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('form').submit(function() {
            email = $('input[name=email]').val();
            $.post("/scripts/addemail.php", {email_address:email}, function(data){

               if(data == "invalid") { 
                alert("invalid"); 

               } else if(data == "used") { 
                alert("used"); 

               } else if(data == "success") { 
               alert("success"); 

               } else {
                alert("error"); 

               }
            });
        });
    });
```

and my PHP:

```
<?php

mysql_connect ('localhost', '********', '********') ;
mysql_select_db ('Blog');

function check_email($input) {

     $input = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($input));

     $checkaddress = "SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email='$input'"; 
     $query = mysql_query($checkaddress);

     if (!eregi("^([_a-z0-9-]+)(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$", $input)) {
          return "invalid";
     } else if ( mysql_num_rows($query) >= 1 ) { 
        return "used"; 
     } else {
        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO emails (email) VALUES ('$input')");
        return "success";
    }
}

$email = urldecode(implode(file('php://input')));
$result = check_email($email);
echo $result;
?>
```

The problem is that its going to the action="/scripts/addemail_fb.php" instead of the jQuery. I'm new to AJAX, and AJAX with jQuery, but I've been using jQuery for quite some time.

I think there are two problems: I don't think that the information is being sent to the jQuery correctly, and I'm not sure how to deal with the key:value pairs (email_address:email) in PHP. Thanks for any help! And yes, I'm obviously a beginner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add a `return false;` inside the form's submit function to prevent default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing your input of type "submit" to "button".  Then add your jquery code to the "onclick" event for that button.  so..instead of "$('form').submit()..." you should use

```
$("#nameofSubmitButton").click(function(){
 //do your stuff here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an onSubmit event handler, either explicitly in the form tag, or implicitly attached to it via DOM/jquery, pointing to your function.

Answer (score 0):

you can set your form action to be

```
<form action='javascript:yourAjaxFunction();'></form>
```

Then when the form is submitted, it will run the javascript function that you define. And if you're using jquery, you can use the .serialize method for the form to get all of the variables into a querystring that you can send in your ajax call.